Chrome problem of blank canvas in the release of May 2024
Just to share with you the annoying problem of canvas blank problem when changing tabs (Chrome version 125.0.6422.61 to 126.x.x.x)
Original issue:
https://issues.chromium.org/issues/328755781
The solutions can be found in the comment:
Here are a few things users can do to mitigate the issue temporarily:

Use Chrome Canary, 127.0.6486.0 and later should not have the issue anymore
Diable canvas GPU acceleration, chrome://flags/#disable-accelerated-2d-canvas. This should not be required past the next release

We tried alot of ways and now find this solution.

I also hit this issue when MS Edge is upgraded, how to solve it in HTML/JS code?

I suppose that we should use the workaround: 2. Disable canvas GPU acceleration, chrome://flags/#disable-accelerated-2d-canvas. When waiting for new chrome/edge version.

I didn't hit this  issue in the latest Chrome and FireFox, only hit in Edge.
